# Why don't some of my applications show up in the launcher when opened?

Tags: 11.10, launcher, window-management

Sometimes when I open an application, the program will open, but it won't display in the launcher or in the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> dialog. Here's a screenshot of VLC open:

[image: VLC Open]

As you can see, the icon doesn't appear in the launcher even though it's clearly open.

I'm also not able to drag the VLC icon from the dash into the launcher, like I can with other programs.

Right now I can only get it to work with VLC, but the other day it also happened to Transmission. Note that some other applications (e.g., Terminal, Chromium, etc.) are all fine.

Also, it's not always this way. VLC was working just fine yesterday, for example, but then this morning it stopped.

It's really frustrating because I have no way of accessing that window other than minimizing everything else to make sure nothing covers it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just my thought, not sure if it's the right direction:

In Compiz Config, go to "Opacity, Brightness and Saturation" and try to add a window specific setting. There's a tool which lets you "grab" some information about any window. Test your mysterious app window with that tool and tell us if there is anything special.

Comment: This actually hasn't happened in a really long time. I suspect it was an early 11.10 bug that was fixed (it appears I posted shortly after 11.10 came out). If it does happen again, I'll do this and let you know.